# How to create star schema from csv files of different schema using ETL talend

Tags: talend

I need to apply ETL process on many csv files having different schema, to load them at the end into a single star schema.

How can I do that using talend ETL tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly import the csv file into talend. Create a job tom move csv data to database. In output component (if oracle tOracleOutput) you have an option to create table if it does not exists. Like wise you can import all the csv files and create schema in the database.

[image]

Thank you